# x509 Go package - ParsePKIXPublicKey is to DER or PEM?

Tags: go

I'm trying to get an object of rsa.PublicKey and I made these steps:

```
 ----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----
           ....
 ----END RSA PUBLIC KEY----
```

```
package main

import (
   "crypto/rand"
   "crypto/rsa"
   "crypto/x509"
   "encoding/pem"
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

 key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./new_public.pem")
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
 }

 block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(key))
 if block == nil {
    fmt.Println("unable to decode publicKey to request")
 }

 pub, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
 if err != nil {
     panic("failed to parse RSA encoded  public key" + err.Error())
 }

 switch pub := pub.(type) {
 case *rsa.PublicKey:
     fmt.Println("pub is of type RSA:", pub)
 default:
     panic("error")
 }
```

}

After this, when I try to `x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)` I get an error:

```
panic: failed to parse RSA encoded  public keyasn1: 
structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:129 isCompound:false}) 
{
 optional:false 
 explicit:false 
 application:false 
 private:false 
 defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> 
 stringType:0 
 timeType:0 
 set:false 
 omitEmpty:false
} AlgorithmIdentifier @3
```

So, I read some blogs and documentations about DER and PEM formats, and they are differents ways to encode an certificate, basicaly one use base64 and other is just bytes.

In x509's package of Golang, the x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey says:

`ParsePKIXPublicKey parses a DER-encoded public key. These values are typically found in PEM blocks with "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"`

And, in the example of this function use the pem.Decode().  I'm very confused about this because this should use `pem.Decode` or something like `der.Decode()` ?

Also, what's the real difference between `x509.ParsePKCS1PublicKey()` and `x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey()` ? Both do the same job to get a rsa.PublicKey ?

Comment: How did you create the keys? I've found that the go libraries can't parse the keys when they're created by openssl. You have to actually create the keys using go's key creation code. It's kind of a weird issue. I'll post a link when I get to work for the go code to do the creation.

Comment: This key was created in Ruby's legacy service, and I just tried to encrypt a token with this PublicKey.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like the issue is with the ruby generated certificates. Try the solution I posted and see if the certificates that that generates works for you. My guess is that it's the same issue I ran into when creating certificates with openssl. The error looks like the same error I was getting.

Comment: @BenjiVesterby The issue you're both experiencing is to do with different encodings.  There are multiple ways (PKCS#1 and PKCS#8) to encode RSA keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is understanding the difference between `x509.ParsePKCS1PublicKey` (PKCS#1) and `x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey` (PKCS#8).

Usually when the PEM header has the type as `RSA PUBLIC KEY`, it is referring to a PKCS#1 encoded RSA public key, which is defined in [RFC 8017 (PKCS#1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1) as:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
     modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
     publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
 }
```

You haven't actually provided the body of your public key (it would be safe to do so), but it is a fair assumption that, if decoding the key using `x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey` failed, your key is likely in the above format (`x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey` uses PKCS#8 encoding).

If this is the case, you should be able to get an `rsa.PublicKey` from the file using the following code (don't forget to add the error handling):

```
rawPem, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./public.key")
pemBlock, _ := pem.Decode(rawPem)
publicKey, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PublicKey(pemBlock.Bytes)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try pasting the key you have into [this site](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) to see what ASN.1 structure it uses.  For reference, the key I used to test this is included here:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEApW1W9dnfdFF7FHrq6HPveR/9T+nM70yO7QOGytR0j/chMBJcJBjG
hJOuKPFbkVyS+BE/4M8CojLgvz4ex82Re0sFa5TqnoWvuP5P4vktR6M5W53sTW3y
gUnfF/oHcEmARQ1xKZdgVnlIfrdbpjecPyLi1Ng4HmhEfCFUOW64koxpb4XeH5O5
q+vc/731ExVOYBU8Sl6kPdjpJuVjS3DHKAVgfVEhscXd3JDjDuMDT3w1IYNb5c2s
wHE55q4Jnc1cr42jdynnkXzmuOGo2C6yD95kbBDLp7wSiBxaMA8gbRkzWJ99T+6l
KsKG2zfndMF3jZW1v1wWiEbYRN07qbN0NQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

[image: ASN.1 Structure of reference RSA Public Key]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

You have to generate the certificates using the code above.

Like this:

./generate_cert --host="source:destination" -rsa-bits 1024

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -out privatekey.pcks8

openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem  > publickey.pem

This should solve the issue for you and give you the files you need.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.